# Что такое стек и куча?

Tags: c#

Я изучаю C# и пытаюсь понять что такое стек и куча. В большинстве примеров, стек подается как массив у которого есть функции push() и pop(). Но это не достаточное объяснение для меня. Вот к примеру, у нас есть функция Calculate()

```
void Calculate()
{
int x;
int y;
object z;
}
```

Какую роль в этом примере играет стек, а какую роль играет куча?

Comment: В этом -- никакую. Можете посмотреть IL-код и сами убедиться в этом.

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/programming-concepts-stack-and-heap/ вот ещё есть короткая статья по теме

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Если рассматривать язык c# сам по себе, в отрыве от реализации, то действительно знать о том, что такое "стек" вам нет необходимости.

Но если вы хотите хорошо понимать тот инструмент, которым пользуетесь, то можно посмотреть немного под капот.

Платформа Microsoft .NET использует стековый байт-код Intermediate Language (IL, CIL, MSIL).

То есть код, который вы напишите, будет записан в опкодах этого языка и уже непосредственно его и будет выполнять CRL.

Посмотрим на какой-либо простой код c# и на то, как он записан опкодами:

```
void Main()
{
    int a = 15;
    int b = 10;
    int c = a - b;
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}
```

IL-код я получил в программе Linqpad, в IL DASM будет такой же:

```
IL_0000:  nop         
IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s    0F 
IL_0003:  stloc.0     // a
IL_0004:  ldc.i4.s    0A 
IL_0006:  stloc.1     // b
IL_0007:  ldloc.0     // a
IL_0008:  ldloc.1     // b
IL_0009:  sub         
IL_000A:  stloc.2     // c
IL_000B:  ldloc.2     // c
IL_000C:  call        System.Console.WriteLine
IL_0011:  nop         
IL_0012:  ret
```

Что мы видим при наведении мыши на ldc или stloc? Мы видим всплывающие подсказки "pushes int value onto stack" или "pops value from top of stack".

[image: IL code with tooltip]

То есть все ваши инструкции на c# оказываются очень тесно связанными со стеком. Даже простые операции типа сложения чисел проходят через стек. И циклы фактически тоже разворачиваются в стековые инструкции.

Это как раз устройство нижележащего этажа для c#. Современные языки программирования достаточно часто используют концепцию стековых машин, c# -- один из них.

PS Если хочется погрузиться в эту тему более основательно, то хорошей отправной точкой может стать статья [Введение в MSIL [Кенни Керр, пер. Aquila]](https://vxlab.info/wasm/publist.php-list=29.htm)

Comment: Тем не менее, этот стек не имеет прямого отношения к реальному стеку ОС. Скомпилировав этот код в Release-режиме, после JIT получаем https://pastebin.com/Y65FkHyr // В абстрактной машине IL нет регистров, вместо них используется стек. В коде после JIT регистры используются, так что однозначного соответствия нет.

Comment: @VladD Я хотел про это расписать подробно, так писал на ассемблере 8080 и Z80, но в итоге вычеркнул всё написанное. До регистров процессора, страниц памяти действительно есть ещё куча слоёв абстракций, я лишь показал первый слой. По-моему для ответа спрашивающему достаточно.

Answer (score 12):

В языке C# понятий «стек» и «куча» нет вовсе.
Вместо них есть область жизни объектов.

Объекты значимых типов живут от точки объявления до конца охватывающего блока (если это локальные переменные) или от начала до конца жизни содержащего объекта (если это поля). Объекты ссылочных типов живут от момента вызова `new` до момента, когда их съест сборщик мусора (а это случится гарантированно не раньше того, как у вас пропадёт последняя ссылка на объект).

То, что локальные переменные значимых типов часто попадают в системный стек — не более чем деталь реализации текущей Майкрософтовской CLR. Знать об этом интересно, но не обязательно.